# How do I configure FF7.0.1 for JMeter

Tags: proxy, jmeter, performance-testing

I am following a tutorial but it does not say how to configure your FF to use the proxy?
I go to `Edit -> Preferences -> Network Tab -> Click on Settings -> Manual proxy configuration`.

What do I type in HTTP Proxy and No Proxy for?
I checked the `"Use this proxy server for all protocols"`?

I have typed in the ip address of the server where my website is hosted and used port 80,
I typed in localhost, 127.0.0.1 into the `"No Proxy for"` box.

I have set up jmeter according to the [tutorial](http://zacster.blogspot.com/2008/03/quick-howto-to-setup-jmeter.html).

I then press start on jmeter and open my website and log in.
I then press stop and nothing happens in the jmeter left pane?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure that Target Controller for ProxyServer set correctly (HTTP Proxy Server):

[image]

...or use better guides:

[JMeter proxy Step-by-step](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf)

[JMeter 101: Using HTTP Proxy to Record your Test](http://girliemangalo.wordpress.com/2009/03/18/jmeter-101-using-http-proxy-to-record-your-test/)

Maybe you also find useful any FF addon like SwitchProxy Tool or [FoxyProxy](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/foxyproxy-standard/) for quick enable/disable proxy.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the instructions for configuring JMeter and your browser:

```
http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf
```

This pdf document contains a section named "Configure your browser to use the JMeter Proxy" from where you can get guidance for configuring FF to use JMeter (specially for recording tests)